# How to get all crm steps names and messages from sql db

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I'm using Dynamics-Crm 2016 and SQL for DB, I need to get all the steps that in my DB and active (not deleted\disabled and etc') , I need a query to get that info or the right tables to search in, after googling I couldn't find a direct answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the sdkmessageprocessingstep entity is what you seek. And filter on where statecode = 0.