# Is there a Tool to List all Dynamics CRM plugins Including Hidden Ones?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-365

I am looking for a tool to get a list of all dynamics CRM plugins in an on-premise instance and in particular the hidden ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use xrmtoolbox and it's plugin [sql4cds](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/MarkMpn.SQL4CDS/) or [fetchxml builder](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/Cinteros.Xrm.FetchXmlBuilder/) and query sdkmessage and it's related table. It will give you all the info about your plugins.

few articles for refernce

[How to get all crm steps names and messages from sql db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152654/how-to-get-all-crm-steps-names-and-messages-from-sql-db)

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/magnetismsolutionscrmblog/posts/quick-tip-locate-plugins-and-steps